# std::forward_list and sequence concept requirements

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there some reason why the standards committee chose to implement the API for `std::forward_list` so that it *doesn't* meet the `Sequence` container concept requirements?

The `Sequence` concept requirements specify that the container must be compatible with expressions like:

```
c.insert(it, v);    // insert at position
c.insert(it, n, v); // fill insert
c.insert(it, begin, end);  // insert range
```

... where `it` is an iterator, `v` is an element, and `n` is an integer, and `begin/end` is an iterator range.

There's no reason this API isn't possible with a singly-linked list, since the `insert` functions require an iterator starting position.  But for some reason `std::forward_list` has the `insert_after` functions, which break compatibility with the Sequence concept.

Is there some reason for this?

Comment: What exactly do you mean?`forward_list` is a sequence container (see [sequence.reqmts]/1).

Comment: @Columbo, sequence requirements include an `insert` member function

Comment: .. weird. It's mentioned multiple times in the standard that `forward_list` meets the requirements of a sequence container. Even on cppreference.

Comment: It seems that it also lacks the `size` member function, the  omission of which is documented: "A forward_list satisfies all of the requirements of a container (Table 96), except that the `size()` member
 function is not provided". Presumably the same applies to `insert`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that it's extremely inefficient to insert *before* an element in a singly linked list: You have to start at the beginning and iterate until you find the requested place to insert, making the insert `O(n)` instead of constant time.

Compare to why they don't provide `operator[]` in `std::list` because it would take linear time. Just as `list` doesn't meet the requirements of random access compared to `vector`, `forward_list` doesn't meet all the requirements of sequence compared to `list`.

Comment: But `operator[]` isn't in the table of sequence container requirements, whereas `a.insert(p, t)` is.

Comment: but the `insert` requirements require an iterator position anyway, so it wouldn't be O(N) to insert after... I guess the committee felt it was worth it to clearly name the function insert_after instead of just naming it insert and meeting the concept requirements...  (come to think of it it seems the concept requirements require it to insert before)

Comment: @Siler The insert functions mean to insert the item *before* the requested iterator. How would you do that in a singly linked list? Or would you change the meaning of `insert` for just that one container?

Comment: @MarkB `insert` is `O(n)` time for a vector and deque too. So what?

Comment: @Barry It makes little sense to provide an inefficient insertion on a container whose whole point is to provide efficient insertions.